# github wont publish for me, can you spy what i'm doing wrong

Tags: publish, github-pages

I'm pulling my hair out, github isnt publishing for me.

Can someone spy what I'm doing wrong?

https://github.com/adrianvalverde/prograd.github.io

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are trying to create your github.io page. In order to do this, you must create the git repo with your username. See my case:
https://fernandovbs.github.io/
And the GitHub repo:
https://github.com/fernandovbs/fernandovbs.github.io

Comment: I cannot thank you enough, I really thought I had done that. Anyhow, its proper now and I hope your day is as good as you've helped make mine. :)

Comment: You're welcome ;). Don't forget to mark my response as right. Have a nice day!